# This record has been set by Rod Laver until now - incorrect?

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect

I've got one correct and one incorrect sentence. I don't understand why I cannot say the first sentence as there is only a change in adjectives. One has "set" instead of  "closed".

> This record has been **set** by Rod Laver until now. (*incorrect*)
>
> The bridge has been **closed** until now. (*correct*)

Comment: "This record has been **held** by Rod Laver until now."

Comment: "Set" as in "set a record" is a punctual verb: it is what happens at the moment when a new record is established. It is not used duratively ("hold" would be normal for this, as Peter Shor says). "Close" is also a punctual verb, but "closed" denotes a state, whereas "set" does not (in this sense: it can do in other senses, as "the concrete has set").

Comment: The present perfect "has been" speaks simultaneously of the past and present.  The bridge was closed, and the bridge is closed, that is "until now." The same can't be said for Rod Laver.  Rod Laver did set the record, but does he set the record?  No, he doesn't.  He may have held the record until now, but he doesn't set it until now.  That makes no sense.

Comment: @ColinFine This is what I find extremely difficult. How can I recognize that **set** is not used duratively but the **hold** is?

Comment: @TH92: I don't know. I think it is just something you have to learn for each (meaning of) each verb.

Comment: Because one can continue to "hold" a record, but once a record is set, a person doesn't keep setting it.  Say that Rob Laver is a sprinter who set the record for the 100 meter dash.  The only way that the first sentence works is if Rob Laver set the record for the 100 meter dash and has repeatedly set a new record every time that race has been run.  Only in that instance could you properly say, "Rob Laver has set the record until now."  The action has to be true of the past AND the present, or right up to the present when you say, "until now."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: I don't see that that helps. When you close a door, it remains closed thereafter: it is true both that it has been closed (punctual action), and that it is closed (state). But when a record has been set, we don't normally say that it remains set (state). This is just an unpredictable difference between the words.

Comment: What makes this concept difficult to explain is the example.  The verb "set" is both the past tense and the present tense.  Also, it makes it hard to illustrate how the present perfect must true in the past and present with the modifier "until now."  "Until now" makes it seem like it's not true in the present when it has been... until now.

Comment: Or to take another example - If I saw you somewhere, then you were seen (punctual action) but we don't say that you are seen (state). I don't think it's anything fundamentally to do with the coincident forms of 'set'.

Comment: @Colin Fine : Whether or not that is normally the case is neither here nor there.  Semantically, when one says that a record "has been set," it remains remains set until someone says otherwise.

Comment: @Colin Fine : "Are seen" isn't the same as "have been seen."

Comment: True. But _has been closed_ has two readings, one of which _is_ compatible with _until now_.

Comment: This may help me. Can I say: The bridge has been closed by Police until now.  In my opinion this should be incorrect.

Comment: This is actually the "indicative present perfect tense."  I'm working to find source material for this, but it's proving difficult as most grammar guides don't explain it.  They explain the present perfect "has set," but not the indicative present perfect "has been set."  Most conjugation tables don't even bother to show this conjugation, so it may take a few minutes, maybe longer.

Comment: It pays off to wait for things like this. Thank your for your time looking for something which could help me too understand this phenomenon better.

Answer (score 1):

The first example

> This record has been set by Rod Laver until now.

is not actually ungrammatical -- it just describes peculiar circumstances.  Suppose Laver set a new record every year throughout the history of the sport, say for example the number of tournaments won on clay in one year, surpassing his own previous performance each year, until the current year, when for the first time, no new record was set, or someone else bested Laver's previous record:

> Since tennis began, Rod Laver won the most clay tournaments each year, and in fact won a greater number of clay tournaments each of those years than he had won the previous year, until this year.

The second example is simpler, since it doesn't have to be interpreted as a passive construction:

> The bridge has been closed until now.

"Closed" can be an adjective describing the state of the bridge which endured from some time long ago up until the present, when the bridge was opened.

(I think this is essentially what Benjamin Harman said above in a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Both examples are unnecessarily awkward.

> "This record has been set by Rod Laver until now"

might be better expressed by saying, for instance,

> "[Rod Laver] set a record of 31 consecutive match victories at Wimbledon between 1961 and 1970, which lasted until 1980 when it was eclipsed by Björn Borg." (Wikipedia) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_Laver

Scroll down to "All-time Tournament Records" to see more.

And,

> "The bridge has been closed until now"

could be improved by saying instead,

> "The bridge had been closed until recently,"

since "now" is a specific and ever-changing point in time and is inappropriately used in the example.